# Setting Fixed margin/padding for WYSIWYG content

Tags: css

I have a page where the content for it comes from a WYSIWYG editor. I want the HTML element to have some fixed margin/padding like "h2" element will always have a margin-bottom as 20px and the paragraph text will have a margin-top as 10px. So the problem is when there is a "p" tag right after the "h2" element then the space between the "h2" and the "p" increases. The spacing between them is the addition of the margin-bottom for h2 and margin-top for p which becomes 30px. Same thing goes if the "p" tag has a margin-bottom as 10p and "span" inside the "p" tag has a margin-top as 5px.

Can we restrict this to 20px always? Is there anyway we can ignore the child element margin-top property if there is a margin-bottom property for the parent?

I have tried using h2+p {margin-bottom: 20px;} which works fine but this is not only about the "p" tag as the content is dynamic and we can expect any HTML element like h3, div, span etc...

Could you please help me out on this?

Comment: Could you shed some light on why you need this? ... I'm asking because there might be other solutions when knowing what for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get is something called "margin collapse" and you can read about it here:
[CSS - Margin-Bottom ignored when Margin-Top exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020680/css-margin-bottom-ignored-when-margin-top-exist)

This will work for block elements like "div", "p" etc. but not for inline elements like "span", "img" etc.

Beyond that you need to add some javascript to iterate through the element collection and adjust margins according to a set of rules you need to setup.